# empty response when using curl_multi_await

Tags: curl, asynchronous, hhvm

I'm testing the example for curl_multi_await from the doc (see the code below), but I can't get any response.
I'm using version 3.8.1 of hhvm.

I had the problem with HH\Asio\curl_exec, but it has been fixed by updating hhvm, is it related?

```
<?hh
  async function curl_exec_await(string $url): Awaitable<string> {
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $mh = curl_multi_init();
  curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
  do {
    $active = 1;
    do {
      $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($status == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    $select = await curl_multi_await($mh);
    if ($select == -1) break;
  } while ($status === CURLM_OK);
  $content = (string)curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
  curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
  curl_multi_close($mh);
  return $content;
}

var_dump(curl_exec_await('http://example.com')->getWaitHandle()->join());
```

This code prints an empty string.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example fixed if it can help someone:

```
<?hh
  async function curl_exec_await(string $url): Awaitable<string> {
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $mh = curl_multi_init();
  curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);

  $active = 0;
  do {
      $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
      await RescheduleWaitHandle::create(
          RescheduleWaitHandle::QUEUE_DEFAULT,
          0,
      );
  } while ($status == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $active > 0);
  await curl_multi_await($mh);

  $content = (string)curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
  curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
  curl_multi_close($mh);
  return $content;
}

var_dump(curl_exec_await('http://example.com')->getWaitHandle()->join());
```

Answer (score 0):

- The function in the docs (that you've copied here) is just an example. It's available in the stdlib as `\HH\Asio\curl_exec`, you can just use that instead of your `curl_exec_await`. See [the docs](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.hack.hh.asio.curl-exec.php).
- If that function still doesn't work, can you check your error logs for any error output, and [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues) so we can track down the problem? Tracking issues there is much better than here on SO.